# How do I remove these top and bottom grey rectangles when rendering google maps in React?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, frontend, maps

[Image of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDCpJ.png)
When I zoom out completely, or pan to the top or the bottom, it pans outside the map. I want the map to always fill the div with no grey areas. I followed their documentation but noticed that the example they have, has this issue too. However when I tested this on google maps website, it doesnt have this issue on there so I am looking for how this is fixed there.

Map.tsx

```
function Map() {
  const [map, setMap] = useState<google.maps.Map>();
  const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    const zoom = 3;
    const center = [0, 0];
    const mapCenter = { lng: center[0], lat: center[1] };
    if (!ref.current) return;
    const generatedMap = generateMap(ref, mapCenter, zoom);
    setMap(generatedMap);
  }, []);
  return <div className="relative h-full w-full" ref={ref}></div>;
}
```

generateMap.ts

```
export default function generateMap(
  ref: RefObject<HTMLDivElement>,
  center: { lat: number; lng: number },
  zoom?: number
) {
  const map = new window.google.maps.Map(ref.current!, {
    center: center,
    zoom: zoom || 15,
    mapTypeId: "roadmap",
    zoomControl: true,
    streetViewControl: false,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    fullscreenControl: true,
    minZoom: 3,
  });
  return map;
}
```

Comment: Please check the duplicate question. You have a full working solution there.